# Django: Associate objects before committing

Tags: python, django, django-registration

So I'm loading a djang-registration Form, which I'm subclassing like so in order to create two related objects, a GeneralUser, and their Business. The below code fails with the warning:

> save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'owner'.

And I have also got warnings in the vein of "NoneType Object has no attribute owner"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'" when trying to create a Business like so :`business = Business(name=self.cleaned_data['business_name'], owner=user)`

I'm simply looking for a way to not commit to db either the user or the business, unless I'm doing it simultaneously. Please note I do **not** have a view for this form to check all sorts of things as `form.isvalid()` because django-registration is taking care of all those views.

```
class GeneralUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    business_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GeneralUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2', 'business_name']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(GeneralUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        business = Business.objects.create(name=self.cleaned_data['business_name'], owner=user)

        if commit:
            user.is_active = True  # TODO: remove before deployment.
            user.save()
            business.save()
            return user
```

How would I go about associating `GeneralUser` with `Business`, and only then committing to the DB?

Comment: check if the user has an attribute 'id', if it has then you can commit business.

Comment: @pramod But a user doesn't have an attribute `id` until he is created in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it then first you should save user then create the Business object. You can't associate the user instance with business object, unless you have committed to the db. The association is actually relationship with the primary key of the user object, which is created only when committed to the db.
Only after, the commit of the user object, the business object can be saved.

You could do something like this,

```
def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs): 
    user = super(GeneralUserForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"]) 
    business = Business(name=self.cleaned_data['business_name'])

    if commit:
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        business.owner = user
        business.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I think I tried this and it doesn't work. It complains because user isn't persisted in database when we try to associate the relationship.

Comment: This returns the error *NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'*

Comment: Edited the answer again.

Comment: Could you print the user after calling super save method and check whether it's saving or not.